# ImportError: cannot import name BayesianGaussianMixture

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to use the Batesian model in `sklearn` but I get the following error when I try.

```
>>> from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name BayesianGaussianMixture
```

I am on `python 2.7.11`. I saw the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html) and I checked the spelling is correct. What should I do it import it?

Answer (score 1):

Update scikit-learn to 0.18, in [previous versions](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.mixture) it was called `VBGMM` (Variational Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Model) - actually it was a bit different method, but it is the closest you will get in previous versions.